# In method use keyof to type parameter

Tags: typescript, methods, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, keyof

Suppose you have the following class:

```
class Foo {
  protected callbacks: Callbacks = {};

  bar(key: string) {
     const callback = this.callbacks[key];
     // do stuff with callback
  }

  ...
}
```

The callback property can be changed (later) by other methods.

How would one make sure the key provided as an attribute is an actual key of the callbacks property?
If the callback instance would be passed to the function, i would do this:

```
function bar<T, Key extends keyof T>(callbacks:T, key: Key) { ... }
```

but that doesn't work with the 'this' keyword. I know using the raw this.callbacks in the generic is incorrect, since this.callbacks is not a type, but a instance. However, converting it with typeof does not yield results either..

```
class Foo {
  protected callbacks: Callbacks = {};

  bar<Key extends keyof typeof this.callbacks>(key: Key) { // Cannot find name 'this'
     const callback = this.callbacks[key];
     // do stuff with callback
  }

  ...
}
```

Am i missing something obvious? Is my entire design pattern flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a pattern to possibly work, you need your class to know in advance the exact keys of its `callbacks` property.  I don't know what type `Callbacks` is supposed to be, but it's apparently not specific enough for what you're trying to do?  Otherwise you'd just annotate the `key` parameter of the `bar()` method as `key: keyof Callbacks`.

Assuming no specific `Callbacks` type works for you, and instead you want to create different `Foo` instances with different `callbacks` keys, you should make `Foo` a [generic class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes), where the generic type parameter (call it `K`) corresponds to the union of keys of the `callbacks` property for that instance:

```
class Foo<K extends PropertyKey> {

  constructor(protected callbacks: { [P in K]: () => void }) { }

  bar(key: K) {
    const callback = this.callbacks[key];
    callback();
  }

}
```

(In absence of more info, I'm assuming that all properties of `callbacks` can be called with zero arguments.)  Since the `callbacks` property has function-valued properties at the keys in `K`, then the `bar()` method's `key` parameter can safely be `K`.  Let's test it out:

```
const foo = new Foo({
  sayHello() { console.log("HELLO!") },
  sayGoodbye() { console.log("GOODBYE!") }
})

foo.bar("sayHello"); // HELLO!
foo.bar("sayGoodbye"); // GOODBYE!
```

Once you create `foo`, the compiler infers it to be of type `Foo<"sayHello" | "sayGoodbye">` due to the callbacks object passed in.  And thus `foo.bar()` can only be called with `"sayHello"` or `"sayGoodbye"` as its parameter.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8BpaBTAHgF3QOwBMYAFAJ3gAd1TsBPFdWgPmgG8Aod6aYePCbKQCuwbPFIAKCuVyj0BHmBAgARmGABrCAC420ANrFoASzzQUAXV0SAlNAC8LAG7xjCgL53W0d525rJDUZdFC8ubh4+AUVlNU0HaGwAC2MIADpgJVV1LX0g2gsAbnDuTNic22LuX3Ya3n5saAAzRAS8dAB3OEQJDm4IMFoACXRleFs9eoh4EHQ0kHgAcwkAIiGAUQAZTYB5AEIVu3cAGnCB2gBxRAIVWnQJ7ymZuYXllYudnYARACEATXWByOtRsnBa8DSAVW5xGY0OhWgAHpEdANtt9uxwZCwJIVucrvAbnd4UiUR9vv9AUA)